# I'm having a problem when running Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

When I open a new project I am shown this problem

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jV0R.png)

Comment: Please add more info on the problem *in the question body*. (e.g. not as an image)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings > Gradle. Then Uncheck Offline Work. Connect PC with Internet and Sync Project with Gradle.